# Mostrar resultado de View no PHP

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, pdo

Boa noite,

Preciso mostrar o resultado de uma view que criei no Postgres, porém não obtenho nenhum retorno.

View no Postrgres:

```
 CREATE VIEW VW_RELATORIO03 AS
 SELECT EXTRACT (MONTH FROM DATSOLPED) AS MES, COUNT(*) AS CONTADOR, 
 SUM(VALPED) FROM PEDIDO WHERE DATSOLPED between '01/01/2017' and 
'31/12/2017' GROUP BY MES ORDER BY CONTADOR DESC
```

Função que busca o relatório:

```
function buscaRelatorio03(){
        include("db/conexao.php");
    $comando = $conexao->prepare("SELECT * FROM VW_RELATORIO03");
    //executando o comando
    $comando->execute();
    return $comando;}
```

Mostra o retorno em uma tabela:

```
    $lista = buscaRelatorio03();
        if(isset($lista) && $lista->rowCount() > 0){
            echo "<th>MÊS</th>";
            echo "<th>QUANTIDADE TOTAL</th>";
            echo "<th>VALOR TOTAL</th>";
            while($linha = $lista->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $linha["mes"] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $linha["contador"] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $linha["sum"] . "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";   
        }
        }
```

Obs: mes,contador,sum são os campos que retornam na view.